# How to set the focus a new record/field

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

When I add a new record to a Table view,  it shows like this:

[image]

How can I get the field ready for input so that it is highlighted and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You mean a focus ring?  It should appear by default if you laid this out in a XIB, just make it the first responder.

Comment: I did lay this out in  XIB.. I wonder what I did so that it's not there by default..

Comment: Can you tell me the way to make it the first responder? It is marked as default in the XIB.

Comment: When the cell is created (I presume you bound this to a model of some kind), you need to grab a reference to it, and make it's textfield the first responder (literally a message called `-makeFirstResponder` needs to be sent to the textfield).  It's very implementation-specific as to how to go about doing it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I got it.. If you make it an answer, I can close out the question..